# DataGridView not getting columns from DataTable when binding

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that I am binding to a table. After I do the following code:

```
Dim filterTable As New DataTable
filterTable.Columns.Add("KeyName")
filterTable.Columns.Add("Path")

GridView.DataSource = filterTable

GridView.Columns.Count remains 0.
```

Basically, the `BindUnidentifiedKeys(UnidentifiedKeys As Dictionary(Of String, String), ByRef GridView As DataGridView)` is called.

I call it like this:
`UnidentifiedKeysManager.Instance.BindUnidentifiedKeys(UnidentifiedKeysManager.Instance.GetKeys, grdUnidentifiedKeys)`

I pass it a dictionary and a `DataGridView`, by reference.

Yet when I set it's datasource to a datatable that has columns, the `GridView`'s columns remain `0`. I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When binding to a DataGridView, take note of the property **AutoGenerateColumns**.  If you set this property to True when you bind the data table to the DataGridView, it will generate columns based on the columns as defined in the data table, which may be what you're after:

```
Dim filterTable As New DataTable
filterTable.Columns.Add("KeyName")
filterTable.Columns.Add("Path")

GridView.AutoGenerateColumns = True
GridView.DataSource = filterTable
```

Alternatively, you can go in the designer and create your columns in the DataGridView manually. When doing this for bound gridviews, set each column's **DataPropertyName** property which will bind the gridview column to the corresponding column/field in the data table (make sure to preserve column order in both). In this case, you'd want to NOT auto generate columns. You can also do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The `GridView` does not have any columns, in this case, the `DataTable` does. The `GridView` has it's own column collection and it is not the same as it's `datasource`.

Comment: Well, I have been doing it the same way for another GridView and it worked without a problem. But basically I can access GridView.DataSource.Columns, however the problem is that I am dynamically setting the GridView's column's widths. So right now if I try to do GridView.DataSource.Columns(0).Width, it will fail. If I do GridView.Columns(0).Width, it will fail as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `BindingSource` and set it's `DataSource` to your `filterTable`, and then set the DataGridView's `DataSource` equal to the `BindingSource`.

Example:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = filterTable;
GridView.DataSource = bs;
GridView.Refresh();
```

Check out also the documentation...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I tried that just now, but my column count is still 0. It's so strange because I'm doing this for a few other GridViews too, and they are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to ensure columns were always present on occasion..

```
GridView.Columns.Clear();
GridView.DataSource = null;
GridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
GridView.DataSource = datasource
GridView.DataMember = "Table1";
```